# How to call C# function from C++ background task (Windows Universal app)?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm rewriting my app (with custom live tiles) to an Universal App. Previously, I used a 3rd party library to render these custom live tiles. This library is not supported anymore, so I have to find a new way to do this. It seems that the [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df) is the only way forward for now, but this is in C++.. And the rest of my application in C#.

My background task is supposed to get data from public API's (e.g. weather), and use this information to render the live tile. I have already written the classes to fetch the data (I also use them in the main app), but these are written in C#.

Now, with the Windows Runtime Components it should be possible to 'mix' different languages (right?). But how do I achieve this? (Concrete samples are missing).

In short: **how can I call C# functions (that will return data) from my C++ background task**?

I have created a very sample - I'd like to run RunTheFunction and RunAnotherFunction from my C++ background task.

```
public class StackOverFlowExampleClass()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class StackOverFlowExampleClass2()
{
    public string UpperString { get; set; }

}

public async Task<StackOverFlowExampleClass> RunTheFunction(int ParameterValue)
{
    StackOverFlowExampleClass overflowClass = new StackOverFlowExampleClass();
    overflowClass.Name = "Stack Overflow";
    overflowClass.Value = 1 + ParameterValue;

    // DO SOME COOL ADVANCED HTTP STUFF
    return overflowClass;
}

public async Task<StackOverFlowExampleClass> RunAnotherFunction(string ExampleString)
{
    StackOverFlowExampleClass2 overflowClass2 = new StackOverFlowExampleClass2();
    overflowClass2.UpperString = ExampleString.ToUpper();

    return overflowClass2;
}
```

**In a normal C# background task I'd do this:**

```
StackOverFlowExampleClass SFClass = await stackoverflowexample.RunTheFunction(10);
StackOverFlowExampleClass2 SFClass = await stackoverflowexample.RunAnotherFunction("stackoverflow");
///// render SFClass.Value + SFClass.Name as a PNG
///// set tile title to SFClass.UpperString
```

How do I do this in C++?

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't write your background task in C# and call through to the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask from that?

Comment: This is not recommended due to memory issues. There was a sample here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43295c90-43e8-4b08-8a25-958a1c3d0a0b/explanation-on-windowsuixamlmediaxamlrenderingbackgroundtask?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK

But it didn't work out.. The code generates a corrupt image.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that your whole question is "not recommended due to memory issues"?

Comment: I was talking about generating the tiles.. that's what takes up memory. If the background task is in C++ (and doing the rendering) then I guess I'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the  [Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151), some nifty examples to do things like:
    __await FileIO::WriteTextAsync(file, file->Name);

It doesn't look as nice yet, and it is likely the standard evolving, new and better (at least standard) ways to do this will emerge in future versions.

Comment: I have installed it, can you give an example on how to use that with the code mentioned above? I'm confused on how to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try using COM for this (though I'm not certain it's a good fit):

C# side:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharp
{
    [Guid("62D276EB-FABE-4c0e-BF59-7D0799DEC029")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IExampleClass
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Value { get; set; }
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("4E196599-F1C5-4447-84F4-E46FC1C16105")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ExampleClass : IExampleClass
    {
        public ExampleClass()
        { }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    [Guid("72D276EB-FABE-4c0e-BF59-7D0799DEC020")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IExampleClass2
    {
        string UpperString { get; set; }
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("6712709D-8913-4911-8ABB-BFB4865D4E9F")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ExampleClass2 : IExampleClass2
    {
        public ExampleClass2()
        { }

        public string UpperString { get; set; }
    }

    [Guid("1C312E27-6B09-412c-B7AA-55F4E0FBCF8C")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ICSharpFunctor
    {
        ExampleClass RunTheFunction(int ParameterValue);
        ExampleClass2 RunAnotherFunction(string ExampleString);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("9B8FAFEA-64EB-493f-95CB-B0B0EDEBADC2")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class CSharpFunctor : ICSharpFunctor
    {
        public CSharpFunctor()
        { }

        public ExampleClass RunTheFunction(int ParameterValue)
        {
            ExampleClass instance = new ExampleClass();
            instance.Name = "Stack Overflow";
            instance.Value = 1 + ParameterValue;
            return instance;
        }

        public ExampleClass2 RunAnotherFunction(string ExampleString)
        {
            ExampleClass2 instance = new ExampleClass2();
            instance.UpperString = ExampleString.ToUpper();
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to take the C# code and generate an assembly, manifest and tlb file for import to the C++ code.

C++ side:

```
using namespace CSharpCOM;
ICSharpFunctorPtr pCSharp;
HRESULT hr = pCSharp.CreateInstance(__uuidof(CSharpFunctor));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    IExampleClassPtr e1 = pCSharp->RunTheFunction(10);
    assert(e1->Value == 11);
    std::string name = e1->Name;
    assert(name == "Stack Overflow");
    IExampleClass2Ptr e2 = pCSharp->RunAnotherFunction("stackoverflow");
    std::string uc = e2->UpperString;
    assert(uc == "STACKOVERFLOW");
}
```

Here's is a link to a full example (including some bits I missed about interfaces.)
https://github.com/brandon-kohn/CSharpCOM

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried out your steps, but I got stuck generating the tlb file. For that, I have to enable 'Register for COM interop' in the project properties - but this checkbox is greyed out. Output Type is set to 'class library'.

Comment: You don't have to enable that. I have a COM project I created which doesn't use that. You can setup the manifest so that you don't have to register the assemblies. Which version of visual studio are you using? I can throw together a tiny example and put it on my github.

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain the link to the fully working example.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Move the C# code into a Windows Runtime Component.
2. Create a wrapper Windows Runtime Component for the C# code
3. Make the C++ code a Windows Runtime Component.
4. Create a wrapper Windows Runtime Component for the C++ code.

After you have done one of those you can use the component in C++,C# or JavaScript is if it were written in the language you are using.

---

Building Windows Runtime Components with C++

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/Building-Windows-Runtime-Components-with-Cpp

Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx

Creating Windows Runtime Components in C++

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441569.aspx

A good example of number 4 is SQLite-WinRT which can be found here http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/